# Lead Acid battery dropped to 6V

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I left my lead acid battery in my scooter and have not touched it for last 3 months. Now the open circuit voltage is only 6V. Is my battery permanently dead, or is there a way to repair it?

Comment: What terrible conditions was it in that three cells died?

Comment: it's probably dead, but it's cheap to try recharging it...

Comment: Refill with destilled water to max level, apply current limited 16V until current has dropped a lot and let it bubble slowly for an hour more. If it doesn't revive it, nothing short of a polarity reversal in a water bath is going to.

Comment: My scooter has an alarm system, I think it has been overdraining current out of it. I've tried a lead-acid battery charger, it's stuck on testing and trying to save the battery
Anway, it says it's a sealed type battery and also says never to add water. Should I open it anyway?

Comment: If it's sealed there's no use opening it as it will very likely be **gell** based instead of having a fluid inside. You could try reviving it if you have a lab supply or another device which can slowly charge it. In general though, deep discharging (and that's what has happened here) is the **end of story** for a lead-acid based battery. When you get a new battery, also get a  trickle-charger or some device that keeps the battery topped-up and use that next time you don't use your scooter for a long time.

Comment: I have an Optimate 4 but it gets stuck on testing and saving battery. Maybe something could be done with a bench power supply, how slowly should I charge the battery?

Comment: I would set the bench supply to 1 A and 14 V and see if that will recover the voltage. You have not mentioned the battery capacity, for a scooter my guess is 5 to 10 AmpHours, perhaps? 1A should always be safe. If the battery is 10Ah I would dare using up to 5A for some minutes and check if that raises the voltage.

Comment: It's a Yuasa YTX7A-BS, 12V 6Ah battery. I will try charging at 1A for like a day and see what happens.